# Google Apps for Work - Calendar API - Read All Organisation Employees Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-api-python-client

In our organisation, we use "Google Apps for Work" and I need periodically export all employees calendar data for automated statistics calculations of their time spend on meetings.

Could you hint me if it is possible?
For now, [the official solution I found](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) require each user sign-in trough OAuth with granting permission to that my application to access their calendar, what is more, granted credentials will expire at some point.

However I need to achieve the same result but as "back-end service" with admin privileges without User sign in and app approval, is it possible?
Or google calendar considered to be a private thing even for "Google Apps for Work" and each user need to grant permissions individually?

Thank you in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**However I need to achieve the same result but as "back-end service" with admin privileges without User sign in and app approval, is it possible?**

What you're looking for are [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). With service accounts you are able to access data on behalf of users in a domain which is sometimes referred to as "delegating domain-wide authority". And fortunately enough, you can use this for Google Apps for Work.

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for
>   example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an
>   application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps
>   domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API
>   to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain
>   would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on
>   behalf of users

Here's a snippet using Python when [using a P12 file](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount):

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

client_email = '123456789000-abc123def456@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
client_email, '/path/to/keyfile.p12', scopes=scopes)
```

[Retrieving all calendar resources](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/#calendar_resource_retrieval_examples)

To retrieve the first page of resource entries associated with a particular calendar, send an HTTP GET request ending with a forward slash to a resource feed URL. Include the Authorization header as described in Authenticating.

```
GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/{domain name}/
```

Optionally, you can send an HTTP GET request with an empty string in the start parameter to a resource feed URL.

```
GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/{domain name}/?start=""
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped very much!